# ExtJS - CheckColumn in the Grid does not appear in production build

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, extjs5, sencha-architect

I have a checkbox column defined in a grid. When I run the application locally, the checkbox is appearing fine. But when I built it and upload it on server, I can't see the checkbox appearing. The entire column appears as `BLANK`.

Code of the checkbox column:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'FLAG',
    text: 'Set Flag?',
    flex: 1,
    listeners: {
        checkchange: 'onCheckcolumnCheckChange'
    }
}
```

`FLAG` is defined as Boolean in the model:

```
Ext.define('App.model.FlagModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.field.Boolean'
    ],

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'ID'
        },
        {
            name: 'DS'
        },
        {
            type: 'boolean',
            name: 'FLAG
        }
    ]
});
```

I suspect that some of the `CSS` file is missing while building the app.

What can be the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try adding `uses: ['Ext.grid.column.Check']` in your grid definition.

Comment: 'Ext.grid.column.Check' is already added in "requires:" in my maon view where the grid is lying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cleared my cache and cookies of the browser, closed it and open the application again and I was able to see checkbox rendering in the grid :)